# Ansible regex_search - move pattern string to inventory variable yml yaml file (than using pattern within playbook or task directly)

Tags: regex, file, ansible, ansible-2.x, inventory

Ansible / ansible-playbook 2.9.27

I have the following playbook, and I want to filter (include and exclude) some entries from an object, that I want to define in a groups_vars/.yml file. Pattern to include lines/entries (from the object) and pattern to exclude, will be maintained in this group_vars/ file, so I don't have to change my playbook or role's/task.yml every time.

This is what I have in my group_vars/env_host.yml file.

```
# cat group_vars/env_hosts.yml 
---
# value for system will be found during playbook run.
# ex: system: **dev** or *int* or *qat* or *prd*

regex_pattern:
  primary_servers:
    include:
      - system[:3] + '(primary|remote0[0-9]).*vm00[0-9]'
    exclude:
      - "devremote0[0-9].*vm00[2-9]"
  remote_servers:
    include: 
      - ... some remote server pattern for including host entries from /etc/hosts
    exclude:
      - ... some remote server pattern for excluding host entries from /etc/hosts

vm_hosts:
  # Primary - 3 vm machines
  - "10.20.30.99 devprimaryvm001.devprimary.domain devprimaryvm001"
  - "10.20.30.100 devprimaryvm002.devprimary.domain devprimaryvm002"
  - "10.20.30.999 devprimaryvm003.devprimary.domain devprimaryvm003"

  # Remote 00 - 3 vm machines
  - "10.20.40.99 devremote00vm001.devremote00.domain devremote00vm001"
  - "10.20.40.100 devremotev00m002.devremote00.domain devremote00vm002"
  - "10.20.40.999 devremote00vm003.devremote00.domain devremote00vm003"

  # Remote 01 - 3 vm machines
  - "10.20.50.99 devremote01vm001.devremote01.domain devremote01vm001"
  - "10.20.50.100 devremote01vm002.devremote01.domain devremote01vm002"
  - "10.20.50.999 devremote01vm003.devremote01.domain devremote01vm003"
```

I want ***/etc/hosts*** file for ANY of the primary hosts (listed above) to contain the following entries.

**Example:** Primary side VM001's /etc/hosts file will have the following host type entries (in *IP HostNameFQDN HostName* format):

```
Primary VM001
Primary VM002
Primary VM003
Remote00 VM001 only*
Remote01 VM001 only*
Remote02 VM001 only*
```

**Example:** Primary side VM002 hosts file will have (limited set of hosts for this one):

```
Primary VM002
Primary VM001
```

**This is my playbook** pb.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  vars_prompt:
    - name: hostname
      prompt: "Enter fqdn of host (ex: devprimaryvm001.devprimary.domain) ?"
      private: no
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Set system
    set_fact:
      system: '{{ hostname.split(".")[1] }}'
  - name: Load variables from env hosts yml
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
       - "group_vars/env_hosts.yml"

  roles:
    - role: update_etc_hosts
```

### **This Role has** just **one** tasks/main.yml

```
# Approach #1
#- name: set fact
#  set_fact: 
#    pattern: "{{ system[:3] }}(primary|remote0[0-9]).*vm00[0-9]"
#
#- name: show pattern
#  debug: 
#    msg: "{{ pattern }}"
#

# Approach #2
- name: set fact include_pattern
  set_fact: 
    include_pattern: "{{ regex_pattern[primary_servers]['include'] }}"
- name: show include_pattern
  debug: 
    #msg: "{{ regex_pattern[primary_servers]['include'] }}"
    msg: "{{ include_pattern }}"

- name: Update /etc/hosts as /tmp/hosts for testing
  lineinfile:
    state: present
    path: "/tmp/hosts"
    line: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    

  #If using pattern set_fact variable -- THIS WORKS! i.e. /tmp/hosts get the expected entries
  #
  #when: ( item | regex_search(pattern, ignorecase=True))

  # just get <Env>(Primary vm00N and Remote0[0-9])vm00N hosts -- THIS WORKS too!!
  #
  #when: ( item | regex_search(system[:3] + '(primary.*vm00[0-9])' + '|' + system[:3] + '(remote0[0-9].*vm001)', ignorecase=True))

  # Get all dev[primary|remote] hosts -- THIS WORKS as well!!!
  #when: ( item | regex_search(system[:3] + '(primary|remote0[0-9]).*vm00[0-9]', ignorecase=True))
 
  # My 3rd flexible approach (where Im defining the pattern to include hosts in a group_vars/<yml> file and just want to use that key/value here -- THIS luckily is NOT working!!!!!! :(
  # Pattern based approach -- if this succeeds, then next task/action will be to use state=absent on some regex AKA using regex_pattern[primary or remote servers][exclude] pattern
  when: ( item | regex_search( include_pattern, ignorecase=True ) )
  with_items:
    - "{{ vm_hosts }}"
```

**Output** of running: **ansible-playbook pb.yml**

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
What is fqdn of host (ex: devprimaryvm001.devprimary.domain) ?: devprimaryvm001.devprimary.domain

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]


TASK [Set system]  -- this will get devprimary for system
```

---

```
ok: [localhost]


TASK [Load variables from euh hosts yml] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=group_vars/env_hosts.yml)


TASK [update_etc_hosts : set fact include_pattern] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [update_etc_hosts : show include_pattern] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "system[:3] + '(primary|remote0[0-9]).*vm00[0-9]'"
    ]
}

TASK [update_etc_hosts : Update /etc/hosts as /tmp/hosts for testing] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '( item | regex_search( include_pattern, ignorecase=True ) )' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if ( item | regex_search( include_pattern, ignorecase=True ) ) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): unhashable type: 'list'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/some/playbooks/infra_automation/roles/update_etc_hosts/tasks/main.yml': line 18, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Update /etc/hosts as /tmp/hosts for testing\n  ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=10   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**How can I define the regex pattern OUTSIDE** of the playbook or role's task and use a variable defined in group_vars/ file (where the actualy pattern is defined)? Is this possible.

That way, I can define more patterns for include / exclude and add tasks/actions per pattern (unless it's easy to use *with_nested*) and massage hosts file to what I want.